# Excel: apply conditional formatting if cell contains one of x strings

Tags: arrays, excel, conditional-formatting

What I'm trying to do should be quite simple but I am getting error messages saying that conditional formatting doesn't accept this method.

So I am looking for a fix or an alternative.

What I have is a list of search texts for phone faults

screen broken
wifi not working
bluetooth dead
the dooflip isnt working
etc.

I have also set up a number of common keywords

screen
wifi
bluetooth

By comparing these two we can see that the last one doesn't adhere to any of my common keywords, and so I want it highlighted/ copied somewhere etc. so I can view and take any action.

So far I have attempted to set up conditional formatting to search the terms for the keywords and if it doesn't contain any then highlight it.

```
=ISERROR(SEARCH({"wifi", "bluetooth", "screen"},$H$117))
```

When using this I get informed that conditional formatting does not support arrays (it works fine if I only specify one search term).

If i create a table with all the keywords in and use the following it works, however it will only find direct mataches, and wont search for the word in the cell string

```
=ISERROR(MATCH(<cell_to_change_colour_of>, <keyword_table>,0))
```

So is there another way of doing this?

Comment: Not a nice workaround - but a helper column with "Boring" or "Interesting" based on your above formula (or a combination as an array-formula (entered with Ctrl+Shift+Enter) : `=IF(ISERROR(SEARCH(<keyword_table>,<cell with text>)),"Interesting","Boring")`)... You can then use the helper column value to colour the text, if you want. Or just autofilter on the helper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

my answer requires MOREFUNC addon*

`=REGEX.COMP(A1,"wifi|bluetooth|screen",FALSE)`

this will return true if any of the words appear anywhere in cell A1. `FALSE` in the formula stipulates that it is not case sensitive.

Unfortunately due to Excell's stupid rules it will not work directly in Conditional Formatting box. You will need to place it in a helper column, and point the conditional formatting rule to that column.

---

**MOREFUNC ADDON**

- Morefunc Addon is a free library of 66 new worksheet functions.
- [HERE](http://web.archive.org/web/20111204011358/http://xcell05.free.fr/morefunc/english) is some information (by original author)
- here is the last working [download link](http://www.freewarefiles.com/downloads_counter.php?programid=14922) I found
- here is a good [installation walk-through video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TAofPm4LCRc#t=92)